# kishankumar@KISHANs-MBP ~ % ionic -v zsh: command not found: ionic kishankumar@KISHANs-MBP ~ %

Tags: ionic-framework, macbookpro-touch-bar, chrome-app-developer-tool

when i am installing ionic framework in MACBOOK Pro
find these are errors -   zsh command not found:Ionic

i have tried many solution so how can we resolve.

pls resolve if any person know this solution
kishankumar@KISHANs-MBP ~ % ionic -v
zsh: command not found: ionic
kishankumar@KISHANs-MBP ~ %

Answer (score 0):

To install Ionic, you will need to install NodeJS. Please install the LTS version of NodeJS, this can be downloaded from https://www.nodejs.org

After installing NodeJS, you will need to install Ionic from the command line.

To install Ionic, you will need to enter the following:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

You should be able to check the Ionic version after this is done.